# error no member function declared in class c++

Tags: c++, class, declaration, function-declaration

so, im making a program for uni and im getting this error

> sala.cc:8:30: error: no ‘void sala::inici(int, int)’ member function
>   declared in class ‘sala’  void sala::inici(int a, int b){

That's the only thing I have in my `sala.cc` file, here's my `sala.hh`.
*(keep in mind that since its for uni I have to follow a structure and comment a bunch, since thats all the funtions I'll have to make there's also a lot of junk in there, also, I tried to declare another funtion in my `.cc` like `void sala::posar_prod(string a)` and it worked fine)*:

```
/** @file sala.hh
    @brief Especificació de la clase sala
*/

#ifndef _SALA_HH_
#define _SALA_HH_

#ifndef NO_DIAGRAM
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "PRO2Excepcio.hh"
#endif

/** @class sala
    @brief representa una sala amb una estanteria en la cual s'enmagatzemen els productes

*/

class sala {

private:

    vector<vector<string>> est;
    int n;


public:

    //contructor

    /** @brief constructora de la clase
        \pre hay preparados en el canal de entrada las dimensiones de las estanterias.
        \post los parametros implicitos pasan a tener los valores leidos
    */
    sala();



    //destructor

    /** @brief Destructora de la clase
        \pre cierto
        \post destruye el objecto
    */
    ~sala();

    //modificadors

    void inici(int a, int b);

    /** @brief añadir un producto
        \pre hay sitio en la sala
        \post nuevo producto añadido en el primer sitio disponible
    */
    void posar_prod(string a);

    /** @brief quitar un producto
        \pre hay un producto en la posicion
        \post la posicion esta vacia
    */
    void treure_prod(string a, int f, int c);

    /** @brief mueve un producto de una posicion a otra
        \pre existen las 2 posiciones, hay un producto en la original
        \post el producto de la primera posicion esta en la segunda
    */

    void meure_prod(int f1, int c1, int f2, int c2);

    //consultoras

    /** @brief devuelve el numero de productos en la sala
        \pre cierto
        \post devuelve el numero de productos en la sala
    */

    int mida();

    /** @brief devuelve el id del producto que hay en la posicion
        \pre la posicion es valida i hay un prodcuto en la posicion
        \post devuelve el id del producto que hay en la posicion 
    */

    string posicio(int f, int c);
    //lectura i escritura

};
#endif
```

Comment: i assume your `.cc` file looks like `#include "sala.hh" void sala::inici(int a, int b) { ... }` ?

Comment: nvm, i worked it out, it was some random gch file from an earlier version from the .hh i didnt notice so i asume it was using that file as a reference. just googled them so correct me if im wrong (the error desapeared but im concerned its just a temporary fix)

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_SALA_HH_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: i just copied that from another project, should i just take out the first underscore then? ty both for the quick answers btw

Comment: Drop the leading _and_ trailing underscores. Not a rule, but it's clean and obvious to readers what you mean. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: @RobStarling: That's a misleading comment. "Don't start with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter" is a strict rule; your advice against the trailing underscore is just your personal preference. Mixing fact and opinion like this is not helpful for beginners.

Comment: @MSalters, fair enough. I didn't mean to debate Pete Becker's comment; just to add advice to it.